# TypeError: request.val is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
const post = database.database().ref("/redux-todo/");
    let obj={
            value
        }
    let request = post.push(obj)
    console.log(request.key);
```

I have a statement `console.log(request.key)` its working as expected.However when execute a statement `console.log(request.val())` so it gives error that `request.val` is not a function.

```
const post = database.database().ref("/redux-todo/");
    let obj={
            value
        }
    let request = post.push(obj)
    console.log(request.val());
```

please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the get the data at some location in the database, you have to [query for it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#reading_and_writing_data).  You can't just create a reference and call val() on it.

I suggest you look into using [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) on a DatabaseReference to [fetch the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) at that location.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this in case you are pushing the value to firebase node is returning the key of the new node created after pushing the data.

For getting the value from firebase you should query the newly created node using `child_added` event which is called whenever a new node is pushed and returns the `val()` object of the child. likewise

```
const post = database.database().ref("/redux-todo/");
    let obj={
            value
        }
    let request = post.push(obj)
    // the child added event is called whenever you pushed a child into your node in firebase and we can query it using on() function to get the value of child added.
    post.on("child_added", snapshot => {
       console.log(snapshot.val())
    })
```

Note: If you add multiple child nodes using an object the `child_added` event is called multiple times for each node created.